# Laravel 4 location of migrations and seeding folder

Tags: migration, laravel-4, composer-php, directory-structure, seeding

I'm working on a package hosted on a private satis repo. When I'm starting a new Laravel 4 project I require my package from my repo and it gets installed correctly.
After installing I want to perform some migrations and seeding, but it does not function.

According to the Laravel manual I can perform a migration from a package:

```
php artisan --env=dev migrate --package="kordaat/admin"
```

But that does not work, I have to run like so:

```
php artisan --env=dev --path="vendor/kordaat/admin/src/database/migrations"
```

The above option works, but not as intended.

Inside my package the composer.json looks like:

```
{
    "name": "kordaat/admin",
    "description": "Admin area created by Kordaat.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
    "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Kordaat",
            "email": "xxx@xxxx.xxxx"
    }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "illuminate/support": "4.1.*",
        "illuminate/database": "4.1.*",
        "imagine/imagine": "0.6.*@dev",
        "cartalyst/sentry": "2.0.*",
        "ircmaxell/password-compat": "1.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Kordaat\\Admin": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "src/database/migrations",
            "src/database/seeds",
            "src/controllers",
            "src/models"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "0.1.x-dev"
        }
    },

    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

The seeding files are located (as stated in the composer.json) inside "src/database/seeds"
The migrations are located inside "src/database/seeds" and contains files like:
"2013_07_07_194325_admin_users_table.php" and many more.

I performed a composer self-update,

```
composer self-update
```

a composer update

```
composer update
```

and a composer dump-autoload

```
composer dump-autoload
```

but still no migrations found.

As aspected, when moving the migrations folder outside the database folder inside the root of the src/ folder then it works the way I want it. Besides the wrong folder location.

```
php artisan --env=dev migrate --package="kordaat/admin"
Migration table created successfully.
Migrated: 2013_07_07_194325_admin_users_table
Migrated: 2013_07_07_210428_roles_table
Migrated: 2013_07_07_210933_permission_role_table
Migrated: 2013_07_07_211434_permissions_table
Migrated: 2013_07_17_144758_role_user
Migrated: 2013_07_17_145130_posts
Migrated: 2013_07_17_145413_images
Migrated: 2013_07_17_145631_settings
Migrated: 2013_07_17_150105_companions
Migrated: 2013_07_17_150120_companion_post
```

It must be something really stupid, but I can't find a proper way of doing it. Who can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Does your *vendor/koordat/admin* -package's serviceprovider register as package for the IoC? This could explain why the `--package` parameter doesn't work...

http://laravel.com/docs/packages#service-providers

Comment: The Register function is empty inside my Serviceprovider: `public function register()
 {
  //
 }`